# I stored the attributes and tried to restore the terminal settings, but the program did not restore to the original mode. How do I do?

Tags: c, vt100

I am currently working on a program that renders a green square upon launch. The program allows the user to move the square to the right by two spaces by typing 'd' without an extra Enter and echoing. To restore the original mode where the user needs to type characters followed by Enter and the terminal echoes, the user should type ']' without an extra Enter. However, when I tested this, the program did not restore to the original mode as expected. here is the code

```c
struct termios orig_termios;

void clear_screen()
{
  printf("\033[H\033[J\033[?25l");
  fflush(stdout);
}

void green_square()
{
  printf("\033[42m  \033[0m");
}

void move_cursor(int hx, int hy)
{
  printf("\033[%d;%dH", hy, hx);
  fflush(stdout);
}

void disableRawMode()
{
  tcsetattr(0, TCSAFLUSH, &orig_termios);
}

void enableRawMode()
{
  tcgetattr(0, &orig_termios);
  atexit(disableRawMode);

  struct termios raw = orig_termios;
  raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON);

  tcsetattr(0, TCSAFLUSH, &raw);
}

int main()
{
  int x = 1; // starting position of the green square
  int y = 1;
  enableRawMode();

  while (1)
  {
    clear_screen();
    move_cursor(x, y);
    green_square();
    char c = getchar();
    if (c == 'd')
    {
      x += 2; // move right 2 spaces
    }
    else if (c == ']')
    {
      disableRawMode();
      exit(0);
    }
    usleep(10000); // wait for 100 milliseconds
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled the code with gcc. I ran it by `./a.out`. When I terminated it by ']', the terminal's cursor remained the state of invisible.

I also tried `tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &orig_termios);` it does't work either.

how do i fix it

Comment: First check the return values of all library/system calls.

Comment: `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: Why call `disableRawMode()` before `exit()` when you have registered it with `atexit()`?

Comment: In the function `green_square`, you're a missing a `\n` in the call to `printf()`. Does adding that, or calling `fflush()` afterwards, solve your problem?

Comment: I'm surprised that the standard `getchar()` returns characters before reaching EOL.  I would expect to use a custom function to read a character from file descriptor 0.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I presume that's the point of using `tcsetattr()`.  I haven't verified the actual attributes being set, but one certainly *can* that way make `getchar()` not block until a newline is entered.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use `TCSANOW` instead of `TCSAFLUSH` when you restore the terminal mode?

Comment: @Haris neither the `disableRawMode()` before `exit()` nor `atexit()` works

Comment: @JJJohn, the point is that you don't need *both*.  If one call doen't work then there's no reason to think that two will do better.  Personally, I am not a fan of exit handlers, and you don't appear to gain anything by using one, so it is the `atexit()` that I would drop.

Comment: Your program (+ required headers) seems to work fine for me.  It's hard to be sure that the terminal mode is fully restored, but definitely the ECHO attribute is re-enabled.  What do you observe that makes you think the mode is not restored?  How do you run (and terminate) the program to elicit that effect?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I compiled the code with gcc. I ran it by `./a.out`. When I terminated it by ']', the terminal's cursor remained the state of invisible.

Comment: It's a bit strange that you print to stdout, but apply your terminal settings to stdin.  Both should be tied to the same device, but  IMHO, you should apply input settings to file descriptor `0`, and outhput settings to file descriptor `1`. In the case one (or both) descriptors are redirected, you will still see the desired functionality, working partially, instead of a cmplete mesh.  imho you should save both descriptor settings and restore upon exit (as `tcseta` is almost idempotent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I stored the attributes and tried to restore the terminal settings, but the program did not restore to the original mode. How do I do?

You clarified in comments that you mean that the input cursor remained invisible after program termination.  Naturally so, because you restore only the terminal attributes, and the cursor state is not among these (if the terminal even supports a cursor at all).  The terminal attributes are pretty much all about characteristics of data transfer to and from the terminal device.

Moreover, it is not by setting terminal attributes that your program turns off the cursor in the first place.  Rather, it turns off the cursor by sending the terminal an ANSI escape sequence serving that purpose<sup>*</sup> (`\033[?25l`) during each call to `clear_screen()`.  Thus, if you want the program to turn on the cursor before it terminates then it should send the corresponding ANSI sequence: `\033[?25h`.

Note also that if the program fails to do that -- for example, if it is terminated by a Ctrl-C instead of by typing a ']' -- then you should be able to restore the the cursor by running the `reset` command in the terminal.

---

<sup>*</sup>For some varieties of DEC terminals -- it is in the range of "private" codes designated for manufacturer use, so it may do something different or have no effect at all on other terminals.